# Storing XML dataset in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, dataset, storing-information

I need to save the DataSet, results of a reporting app, to a table in SQL Server 2000. Do I save the datasets the same way I would store files in the DB, via Byte Array()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2000 is really not well equipped to handle XML blobs. It neither has the dedicated XML type, nor does it easily support large text in the form of a VARCHAR(MAX) data type. Both are available in SQL Server 2005 and up.

If you're absolutely and definitely stuck on 2000, your best option is to store your XML into a `TEXT` column (or `NTEXT` - 2 byte per character - if you need to support non-ASCII type character sets like Asian languages, Hebrew, Arabic etc).

Mind you though : the TEXT column data type is not very useful in that you can't really do much on it without a lot of hassle - you can't even really search or replace something on it. It's a mess. None of the usual string method work on it - it's really a "store-and-forget" kind of blob.....

UPDATE: if you will **never** need to inspect the contents of the file while it's stored in the database (really?), you could also use an `IMAGE` data type.

To store the file in SQL Server, do something like this:

```
private void AddFileToDatabase(string filename)
{
   using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=***;database=***;integrated security=SSPI;"))
   {
      string insertStmt = "INSERT INTO dbo.YourTableName(DocFilename, DocContent) VALUES(@FileName, @Content)";

      using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, con))
      {
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", filename);
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@Content", SqlDbType.Image);

          cmd.Parameters["@Content"].Value = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

          con.Open();
          int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          con.Close();
      }
   }
}
```

And basically the same thing for the reading out of the blob of bytes from the database. Or you can package this up in a nice stored procedure - totally up to you.

If you use `TEXT/NTEXT`, you need to store an actual string, e.g. you could not really use a binary file (like Word) - but if you have output from a report as XML or HTML or something, then TEXT/NTEXT would work, too (just use `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Content", SqlDbType.Text);` in that case).

Comment: It's an SQL Server 2000 DB. I just need to store the documents and load them back as needed. I wouldn't be searching inside the documents etc.

Comment: I notice that there is a dataset.GetXML() which returns a string representation of the DataSet. Can't I use that to save to a field if text datatype?

Comment: @Saif: yes, sure - you could get an XML string representing your data set, and store that string into a TEXT/NTEXT field in SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 0):

you can also `serialize` (binary not xml) your dataset and save in database.